# Is Cancellation token in C# not deterministic?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, cancellation-token

If I modify the following code by putting the cancel before creating the task it always stops in the catch. However, if I run it as it is, sometimes stops in the catch, but other times it will print numbers indefinitely.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main()
    {
        var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var task = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{i++}");
            }
        }, tokenSource.Token);
        
        tokenSource.Cancel();

        try
        {
            await task;
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(OperationCanceledException)} thrown with message: {e.Message}");
        }
        finally
        {
            tokenSource.Dispose();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code does not check the status of the cancellation token.

Comment: Then why, it throws sometimes?

Comment: Because sometimes it gets cancelled before the task starts

Comment: So if the task is cancelled before it starts, it throws and doesn't ever start. But if the task has already started it depends on me to throw with ThrowIfCancellationRequested. Thank you!

Comment: Check out this article by Stephen Cleary: [A Tour of Task, Part 9: Delegate Tasks](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/03/a-tour-of-task-part-9-delegate-tasks.html). It should answer all your questions about using the `Task.Run` with `CancellationToken` argument.